# QueryOver with dynamic join and disjuction

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to create a query that, depending on the input of the method, uses a join or not. Given the following model:

```
Account
{
    Group Group;
    Account KeyUserInteral;
    Account KeyUserExternal;
    DateTime DeactivationDate;
}

Group
{
    Account KeyUserInteral;
    Account KeyUserExternal;
}
```

I want to either

- get all `Accounts` that a given different `Account` is entered as either `KeyUser`

or

- get all `Accounts` that a given different `Account` is entered as either `KeyUser` **or** is entered as the `Account.Group`s either `KeyUser`

**and** then depending on the `DeactivationDate` filter that result to include only active `Accounts` or not.

For this, I tried it using this method:

```
public IList<Account> ListByKeyUser(int keyUserId_, bool includeGroupAccounts_, bool onlyActive_)
{
    Account keyUser = Get(keyUserId_);

    Disjunction keyUserRestriction = new Disjunction();
    keyUserRestriction.Add<Account>(acc_ => acc_.KeyUserInternal == keyUser || acc_.KeyUserExternal == keyUser);

    IQueryOver<Account, Account> query = Session.QueryOver<Account>();

    if (includeGroupAccounts_) {
        query.JoinQueryOver(acc_ => acc_.Group, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
            .Where(grp_ => grp_.KeyUserInternal == keyUser || grp_.KeyUserExternal == keyUser);
    }

    query.Where(keyUserRestriction);

    if (onlyActive_) {
        query.Where(acc_ => acc_.DeactivationDate > DateTime.Now);
    }

    return query.OrderBy(acc_ => acc_.Name).Asc.List<Account>();
}
```

Unfortunatley, the created SQL is not exactly what I need: (Excluded the `SELECT` as that's not really interesting I think)

```
SELECT [...]
FROM accounts this_ left outer join groups group1_ on this_.userGroup=group1_.id
WHERE
(group1_.keyUserInternal = @p0 or group1_.keyUserExternal = @p1)
and
((this_.keyUserInternal = @p2 or this_.keyUserExternal = @p3))
and this_.deactivationDate > @p4
ORDER BY this_.name asc;
```

What I need is this:

```
SELECT [...]
FROM accounts this_ left outer join groups group1_ on this_.userGroup=group1_.id
WHERE
((group1_.keyUserInternal = @p0 or group1_.keyUserExternal = @p1)
 or (this_.keyUserInternal = @p2 or this_.keyUserExternal = @p3))
and this_.deactivationDate > @p4
ORDER BY this_.name asc;
```

Basically, I just need to somehow move the "join condition" into the "or". I tried it by adding the where into the disjunction:

```
if (includeGroupAccounts_) {
    query.JoinQueryOver(acc_ => acc_.Group, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
    keyUserRestriction.Add<Account>(acc_ => acc_.Group.KeyUserInternal == keyUser || acc_.Group.KeyUserExternal == keyUser);
}
```

But that creates:

```
SELECT [...]
FROM accounts this_ left outer join groups group1_ on this_.userGroup=group1_.id
WHERE
((this_.keyUserInternal = @p0 or this_.keyUserExternal = @p1)
 or (this_.keyUserInternal = @p2 or this_.keyUserExternal = @p3))
and this_.deactivationDate > @p4
ORDER BY this_.name asc;
```

Which totally ignores the `Group` join...

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more digging returned the following as a solution:

```
if (includeGroupAccounts_) {
    Group groupAlias = null;
    query.JoinAlias(acc_ => acc_.Group, () => groupAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
    keyUserRestriction.Add(() => groupAlias.KeyUserExternal == keyUser || groupAlias.KeyUserInternal == keyUser);
}
```

This results in exactly the SQL I needed, where the "join where" is contained in the "or", while the "datetime check" is still an "and" for everything.

```
SELECT [...]
FROM accounts this_ left outer join groups groupalias1_ on this_.userGroup=groupalias1_.id
WHERE (
    (this_.keyUserInternal = @p0 or this_.keyUserExternal = @p1)
    or (groupalias1_.keyUserExternal = @p2 or groupalias1_.keyUserInternal = @p3)
)
and this_.deactivationDate > @p4
ORDER BY this_.name asc
```